# Bootstrap for wordpress form breaking

Tags: wordpress, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap to build a wordpress site (http://www.graditudemedia.com/) and I put a contact form in the footer. It looks fine when the viewport is bigger than 1215px wide, but the columns overlap below that. It doesn't need to be responsive, so I tried removing bootstrap-responsive.css and that only makes the columns overlap regardless of the viewport size. Kind of a noob, any help would be appreciated. Here's the form code:

```
<div id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12 center">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12 center">
        <p>It’s about time you did something awesome with your brand. Let’s get started.<p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <form class="span10 offset1">
        <div class="controls controls-row">
          <div class="span3">
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on">Name</span><input id="prependedInput" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on">Email</span><input id="prependedInput" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on">Phone</span><input id="prependedInput" type="text">
              </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on">Company</span><input id="prependedInput" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on">Website</span><input id="prependedInput" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on">Budget</span><input id="prependedInput" type="text">
              </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
              <textarea class="span3" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 offset3 controls controls-row center">
          <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-custom">Submit</button>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The responsive CSS @import does need to be removed from the style.css, and then you should also remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` from `header.php`

Comment: Hey thanks @ArleyM. I tried removing that line to, but no dice.

Comment: I still can see it, did you put it back? Your style.css also still contains `@import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
`

Comment: I did put it back. I'll remove it again if you want to take a look.

Comment: I'd love to! Please ping here when you have... I'm so close to having the points needed on Stack Overflow to post comments, haha

Comment: Great! Now a bit of tinkering. Change the form .span10.offset1 to just .span12, and make the children columns of .span3 have a width of 31%. This fixes the overlap!

Comment: That worked great! Thanks. Now how do I get the submit button to center?

Comment: We shouldn't really use Stack Overflow as a chat. Mark this as the answer, and email me: arley at mcblain dot calm.